# How build hash map for key and 2 values in Java?

Tags: java

I want to build hash map to contain

```
<string, array and double(sum(double2).
array contain string, int1, double1, double2 (int1*double1)
```

for example:

```
string1, word1,2,1.1,2.2 , 7.3 (2.2+1.1+4.0)
string1, word2,1,1.0,1.1 , 7.3
string1, word3,2,2.0,4.0 , 7.3

string2, ... 
..
...
stringn,....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really create a class to hold this data. `HashMap`s (and `Map`s in general) are for 'mapping' one thing to something else, not for holding a plethora of unconnected items.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `HashMap<String, MyCustomObject>` where the MyCustomObject holds a String and whatever other fields that are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Commons Pair](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) as the value where Pair contains the array list and the double.

```
Map<String, Pair<List<String>, Double>> myMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like you want to store several data items with a single key in a HashMap?

The simple answer is that HashMap isn't designed to do that. It associates one key with one value.

So, what you need to do is write a custom class to hold all of the data that you want to associate with the key, and then store an instance of that class as the value associated with the key.